# Calculating NDVI index from Tiff images?

Tags: c#, .net, tiff, geotiff, libtiff.net

I have a problem with NDVI Calculating. I use [LibTiff.Net](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) and I'd like calculate NDVI from two Tiff images.

I read many documents (for example:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_Difference_Vegetation_Index ).

I need  spectral reflectance measurement property for NDVI. 
Unfortunately I can't get these property from Tiff Tag's.. Which is the spectral reflectance measurement Tag?

How can I calculate NDVI with BitMiracle Libtiff?